# Big-O Sigma Notation

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory, time-complexity

What is the Big-O of this loop if `someWork(..)` does exactly `i` operations? Algorithm *`someWork(..)` does more work as `i` increases*. How to represent the solution in sigma notation?

```
i <--2
while (i < n)
   someWork (..)
   i <-- power (i,2)
done
```

Firstly, `i <-- power (i,2)` is `O(log n)` and `someWork (..)`  seems to be `O(log n)` too, because it does more work as `i` increases. Multiply both complexities to obtain `O((log n)²)`. Confirm?

Comment: Why? To me it looks to `O(log n)` is the complexity for the entire code posted.

Comment: Wher does this pseudocode come from? there is a question that looks quite similar http://stackoverflow.com/q/24581182/3440545 I cant flag this as duplicate, due to my answer is not accepted or upvoted until now.

Comment: O(log n) seems correct, you just add both complexities because they are equal and in the same loop right?

Comment: `O(log n)` cant be right. `someWork(..)` needs at least `O(sqrt(n))` in the last round of the loop. see my answer for details

Answer (score 3):

In every round of the loop the exponent of `2` will be doubled. So in the `k`-th round the number `i` will be `22k`. 
The loop keeps going as long as `22k < n` holds, which is equivalent to
`k < log log n`. Exactly it is `log₂ log₂ n`, but due to all logarthms are equal exept for a constant factor, I just write `log log n`.

If `someWork()` does `O(22k)` operations in round `k`, you get a total complexity of

```
O( 2 + 22 + 222 + 223 + ... + 22log log n )
```

This simplifys to `O(2 ⋅ 22log log n ) = O(n)`.

To see the simplification take a look at the following:
The number `2 + 2² + 2⁴ + 2⁸` can be written in binary as
`100 010 110`. So you can see that

```
2 + 221 + 222 + ... + 22k < 2 ⋅ 22k
```

holds, since it is equal to `100 010 110 < 1 000 000 000`.

**Edit**:
[image]